# Determine the Winner of a Bowling Game in python

Tags: python, algorithm

> You are given two 0-indexed integer arrays, `player1` and `player2`, which
> represent the number of pins that player 1 and player 2 hit in a
> bowling game, respectively.
>
> The bowling game consists of `n` turns, and the number of pins in each
> turn is exactly 10.
>
> Assume a player hit x<sub>i</sub> pins in the ith turn. The value of the ith turn
> for the player is:
>
> 2x<sub>i</sub> if the player hit 10 pins in any of the previous two turns.
> Otherwise, it is x<sub>i</sub>. The score of the player is the sum of the values
> of their n turns.
>
> Return
>
> 1 if the score of player 1 is more than the score of player 2, 2 if
> the score of player 2 is more than the score of player 1, and 0 in
> case of a draw.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: `player1 = [4,10,7,9]`, `player2 = [6,5,2,3]`
> Output: 1
> Explanation: The score of player1 is `4 + 10 + 2*7 + 2*9 = 46`. The
> score of player2 is `6 + 5 + 2 + 3 = 16`. Score of player1 is more than
> the score of player2, so, player1 is the winner, and the answer is 1.

**My solution does not pass all the test cases for example this one:**

```
Input
player1 =
[3,6,10,8]
player2 =
[9,9,9,9]
Use Testcase
Output
1
Expected
2
```

```
class Solution(object):
    def isWinner(self, player1, player2):
        player_total=0
        for count, player in enumerate(player1):
            if player == 10 and count < len(player1) - 1:
                for player in range(2):
                    player_total += player1[count+1]*2
            else:
                player_total +=player
        player_total1=0
        for count, player in enumerate(player2):
           
            if player == 10 and count < len(player2) - 1:
                for player in range(2):
                    player_total1 += player2[count+1]*2
            else:
                player_total1 +=player
            
        if player_total > player_total1:
            final = 1
        elif player_total < player_total1:
            final= 2
        elif player_total == player_total1:
            final= 0
        return final
```

Comment: Please explain what your solution is trying to calculate, in your own words

Comment: Based on the rules in the assignment, what should player1's score be after hitting `[3,6,10,8]`? What does this code calculate it to be?

Comment: The code calculates the total scores for each player, considering a special scoring rule when a player's score is 10. For each score in player1 and player2, it checks if the score is 10 and if there is a next score available. If so, it multiplies the next score by 2 as well and adds it to the total score. Otherwise, it adds the current score as it is. Finally, it compares the total scores of the two players and determines the winner: 1 for player1, 2 for player2, or 0 for a tie. The method returns the value indicating the winner of the game.

Comment: Right. So, applying those rules (just as pen and paper math), what is player1's score based on hitting `[3,6,10,8]` ?

Comment: The answer should be 35, 3+6+10+8*2

Comment: Agreed, and what is your code calculating it as? If you can step through why that happens, you can probably start to see what's going wrong. Maybe add a print statement each time you increase `player_total`

Comment: i see where i'm going wrong, the loop under the if player = 10, doubles the 8 and adds that twice and then adds the 8 separately but i'm not sure how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

- `player_total += player1[count+1]*2` is executed twice (by the inner loop), but it the index `count+1` remains the same in both iterations, so that you actually add the next value 4 times, and don't do anything for the value that follows after the next.
- After that inner loop has executed, the outer loop will visit that next value in its next iteration, and add that value *again*.
- If the above problems are resolved, then you still have to deal with the case where two consecutive 10 values occur, such that this does not lead to double counting: the value that follows after the second 10 should not count 4 times, but 2 times.

It will be easier if you look backward instead of forward, and keep track of the most recent index where a 10 was encountered.

Not a problem, but avoid code repetition. Put the logic for calculating a player's score in a function, and then call it for each player.

Spoiler:

> `class Solution(object):
>      def score(self, player):
>          laststrike = -3  # As no 10 was encountered yet...
>          total = sum(player)  # all values count at least once
>          for i, pins in enumerate(player):
>              if i - laststrike <= 2:
>                  total += pins
>              if pins == 10:
>                  laststrike = i
>          return total
>
>      def isWinner(self, player1, player2):
>          scorediff = self.score(player1) - self.score(player2)
>          return (scorediff != 0) + (scorediff < 0)`